# how to clean a tomato

Tags: cleaning, tomatoes

How should a standard supermarket tomato be cleaned before putting it in a green salad. Is a quick rinse under running water with light rubbing under the palm and fingers adequate?

Answer (score 1):

From [a quick Google search](https://brownthumbmama.com/wash-tomatoes/):

> you should rinse, rub the surface, rinse again, and dry.

Pretty simple, and it's pretty much what you suggested.  The site claims to be getting their advice from a scientific study, and I'm inclined to believe them, but they don't provide a link.

Comment: I usually scrub them with a bit of washing up liquid as I know in my parts the use semi-treated waste water to irrigate the fields. Additionally if they were sprayed with an insecticide/pesticide a simple rubbing with only water probably won't be enough.